# batch file remove all but the newest 10 files

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I have the following in a batch file:

```
:REMOLDFILES
ECHO Removing files older than 14 days. >>%LOGFILE%
cd /d %BKUPDIR%
FOR /f "skip=14 delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /a:-d /b /o:-d /t:c %1*.zip ^2^>nul') DO IF EXIST "%%~fA" ECHO "%%~fA" >>%LOGFILE%
FOR /f "skip=14 delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /a:-d /b /o:-d /t:c %1*.zip ^2^>nul') DO IF EXIST "%%~fA" DEL "%%~fA" >>%LOGFILE%
FOR /f "skip=14 delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /a:-d /b /o:-d /t:c %1*.log ^2^>nul') DO IF EXIST "%%~fA" ECHO "%%~fA" >>%LOGFILE%
FOR /f "skip=14 delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /a:-d /b /o:-d /t:c %1*.log ^2^>nul') DO IF EXIST "%%~fA" DEL "%%~fA" >>%LOGFILE%
IF [%3]==[Y] GOTO SECONDBACKUPDIR
IF [%3]==[y] GOTO SECONDBACKUPDIR
GOTO END
```

The problem I ran in to is that the backup was not running for a couple of weeks and ended up deleting all of my backups since they were over 2 weeks old.

What I need is for it to keep the last 10 latest backups.

Anyone have an idea how I would do that? I did not write this once since I'm not that familiar with batch files.

Comment: This code should delete all but the most-recent **14** `*.log` and `*.zip` files. Reducing this to 10 will not aid matters. How do you identify whether the backup has been run?

Comment: @Magoo - I noticed that too (my original answer had 14 days because of this), but the OP specifically asked for 10. I suppose he has his reasons (maybe it doesn't run on weekends?).

Comment: What OS are you using? You may be able to use the `forfiles` command, which would easily solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `FOR /F SKIP` to ignore the last 10 most recently modified entries after sorting by last modified date:

```
for /f "skip=10 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d *.zip') do @del "%%F"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! tyvm!

Comment: Wrong! Wrong! Wrong! This code will do precisely the same as the original posted code **except** that it will delete all but the last **10** zip files whereas the original allowed **14** to remain. Otherwise, it's actually *precisely* the same in effect as the original code, other than it only processes `*.zip` files and does not cater for the very slight possibility that there is a directory named `*.zip* present.

Comment: @Magoo - "What I need is for it to keep the last 10 latest backups."

Comment: The original code keeps the last **14** and the complaint is that it "ended up deleting all of my backups since they were over 2 weeks old." The **14** in the original is *not* a number-of-days but a count-of-files. If the original code deleted required data because "the backup was not running for a couple of weeks" then some other method needs to be devised to determine that a backup has been run because **the presence of a .zip or .log** apparently does **not** indicate that a backup has been run.

Comment: Yes I understand, although how were backups removed after 14 days if it's entirely based on file count? It appears they are checking the `creation time` in the original script.

Comment: The only 'time' factor is the creation-time of the files which is used to sort the filelist in the original version. OP's problem is that with `14` versions exempted from deletion, the original procedure deleted **too much** data. This can't be cured by deleting **even more**. Beware - you may get what you ask for, not what you want.

Comment: Awesome one-liner. Thank you so much, you saved me a lot of time !

Answer (score 1):

You can get a listing of files in reverse order by modified date using the `DIR` command. Then you just tell your `FOR` loop to skip the first 10 (**note** your post code shows `14`, but you ask for 10) entries, so whatever is processed is deleted.

```
REM Update to 14 if needed.
SET Keep=10
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* skip=%Keep% delims=" %%A IN (`DIR *.zip /B /O:-D /A:-D`) DO DEL "%%A">>%LOGFILE%
```

Since you are unfamiliar with batch, you can test this command (to see what will be deleted instead of actually deleting it) by replacing `DEL` with `ECHO`.

---

**Edit**

Since you are also processing log files, why not just delete them in the same loop?

```
REM Update to 14 if needed.
SET Keep=10
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* skip=%Keep% delims=" %%A IN (`DIR *.zip /B /O:-D /A:-D`) DO (
    ECHO Processing: %%~nA
    REM Delete ZIP file.
    DEL "%%A"
    REM Delete LOG file.
    DEL "%%~nA.log"
)>>%LOGFILE%
```

Comment: Same problems as the accepted response. You've omitted the `/a-d` to gate-out `*.zip` directories (rare, but can happen in theory.) Good to avoid the un-necessary duplication. Essentially, same in effect as the OP's code, but 10 days in place of 14 - and your code doesn't generate the logfile entries...

Comment: @Magoo - The `DEL` command would fail if passed a directory, but it's good practice to exclude it anyway. Regarding the redirection to the log, you are right - I just flat out missed that.

Comment: True - but without the `/a-d` the directory-name line it would occupy one of the exempt-from-deletion slots, so the directory stays regardless (`del` will fail) but `9`, not `10` **files** would remain if one line in the first 10 is a directory, not a file.