# batch file to remove all but the newest 10 files folder has numerous file names

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a folder that houses our log files. We have numerous processes that create the log files in it's name. Examples are below. I would like to keep the last 10 log files for each process (log file name) and delete any others. I have seen some posts that are close to this ([batch file remove all but the newest 10 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788132/batch-file-remove-all-but-the-newest-10-files)), but they delete all but the last 10 total files. I need the last 10 of the different named files.

```
rm_list_mover_20170510050901
rm_list_mover_20170427050901
rm_list_mover_20170515050902
rm_list_mover_20170514050901
jb_jump_server_20170514050901
jb_jump_server_20170515050902
jb_jump_server_20170514050901
jb_jump_server_20170510050901
lx_star_power_20170510050901
lx_star_power_20170414050902
lx_star_power_20170514050901
lx_star_power_20170515050902
```

I'm completely new to this and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your example doesn't really match your request. Please provide both a sample set of data and the expected output.

Comment: Then prepare a list of possible prefixes and handle them separately/iterate the list. [SO] isn't a script writing service, to get help you should show your own effort in the form of code even if not working as desired.

Comment: Simple solution: `for /F "tokens=1-3* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B /O:-N') do set /A logs[%%a_%%b_%%c]+=1 & if !logs[%%a_%%b_%%c]! gtr 10 del "%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d"`; just insert a `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you did not show any own efforts, I decided to provide a script that fulfils your request as I found it challenging; so here it is:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_LOCATION=."
set "_PATTERN=*_??????????????"
set "_EXTENSION=.log"
set /A "_KEEP=2"

rem // Retrieve unique file name prefixes (with date/time stamp truncated):
if defined _EXTENSION (set "EXT=!_EXTENSION!") else set "EXT=."
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('dir /B /O:-N "!_LOCATION!\!_PATTERN!!EXT!"') do (
    set "FILE=%%F" & set "NAME=_" & set "ITEM="
    for %%N in ("!FILE:_=" "!") do (
        set "NAME=!NAME!!ITEM!_" & set "ITEM=%%~N"
    )
    set "NAME=!NAME:~2!"
    if defined NAME set "$UNIQUE[!NAME!]=#"
)
rem // Delete all but last number of files per unique file name prefix:
if %_KEEP% GTR 0 (set "SKIP=skip=%_KEEP%") else set "SKIP="
for /F "tokens=2 delims=[=] eol==" %%L in ('2^> nul set $UNIQUE[') do (
    for /F "%SKIP% delims= eol=|" %%E in ('dir /B /O:-N "!_LOCATION!\%%L*!EXT!"') do (
        ECHO erase "%%E"
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

After having verified that the correct files are about to be deleted, **remove the upper-case `ECHO` command** in front of the `erase` command line!

I assumed the log files to have got the file extension `.log`. The script can handle files with any number of underscores `_` in their file names. However, it may fail in case any of the file names contain any of the following characters: `!`, `^`, `=`, `[` and `]`.

Comment: Thanks aschipfl that worked! I would like to apologize if I upset anyone. I'm not a cmd-line or batch programmer. I have almost no experience with them. I had been looking around for a while to find an answer, but did not have any luck.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't worry, you did not upset anybody; just show your attempts in your next questions to avoid down-votes and/or close-votes; note that such votes are never meant personally, they only relate to the post itself...