# Windows batch script to delete all except newest 10 files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am new in writing batch scripts. I want to delete all files in my folder except keep the latest `10` file which are backups files of extension `.DMP`.

My folder dump which contains files like:

```
OPD_02_11_2017_14_47_04.DMP
```

Can anybody help me out from scratch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [batch file remove all but the newest 10 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788132/batch-file-remove-all-but-the-newest-10-files)

Comment: based on timestamp or based on filename? If based on filename: there is a reason, why programmers like to use the `YYYYMMDD` format

Comment: Hiii Stephen ,thank you for your reply,actually I want a windows batch script when trigger then delete all files in folder except the newest 7 files based on timestamp(creation of file). lets say we have folder in D:\backup and every day we are generating files like "OPD_02_11_2017_14_47_04.DMP" in same folder using windows batch scripts. now i want to delete all files everyday except latest 7 files based on time stamp.